# Expand (start, end) pairs in a vector

Tags: loops, vector, rust, iterator, tuples

I have a `Vec<(usize, usize)>` of (start, end) pairs that comes from **[`find_iter()`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.7/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find_iter)** and I need that expanded into a `Vec<usize>`. By expanding, I mean that `[(0, 3), (10, 13)]` should be expanded to `[0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12]`. So, each number in between should be in the `Vec`, starting from `start` (inclusive) and going up to `end` (exclusive). I have working code but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it.

Here's a minimal example:

```
use regex::Regex;

fn get_substring_indexes(string: &str, substring: &str) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut indexes = Vec::new();
    for mat in Regex::new(substring).unwrap().find_iter(string) {
        indexes.extend(mat.range());
    }
    indexes
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", get_substring_indexes("git add . git", "git"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) implements [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Iterator) so you can use them as iterators. If you'd like to combine and flatten multiple iterators you can use [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) or in this case [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map). Here's an updated example of your code:

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61049935525c47b96e842d6e01e00cad)

```
use regex::Regex;

fn get_substring_indexes(string: &str, substring: &str) -> Vec<usize> {
    Regex::new(substring)
        .unwrap()
        .find_iter(string)
        .flat_map(|mat| mat.range())
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", get_substring_indexes("git add . git", "git"));
}
```